# Enrich document preamble using pandoc

Tags: luatex, koma-script, pandoc, lua

I use pandoc for generating a PDF file via lualatex from a markdown file. The document class `scrartcl` defines the command `\publishers{}`, which is employed in `\maketitle`. I would like to write a lua filter that extracts the value from a meta data field and adds the command to the preamble.

The markdown file looks like this:

```
---
title:      My very important document
author:     It's me
publishers: This is what I would like to add
...

# Introduction

And so on and on ...
```

This is my filter so far

```
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function Meta(meta)
    -- How to check for a KOMA-Script document class?
    if meta.publishers then
      local publishers = pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.publishers)
      local latex_cmd = '\\publishers{' .. publishers .. '}'
      local raw_inline = pandoc.RawInline('latex', latex_cmd)
      -- How to add the command to the preamble?      
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my questions:

1. How can I check for a KOMA-Script document class in the filter?
2. How can I add the command to the document preamble? Do I need a custom writer for this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a custom template instead of trying to modify the existing template on the fly with filters?

Comment: Using a custom template would be an easy solution indeed. The default template, however, might change in future pandoc versions. Therefore, I try to avoid writing custom templates.

Comment: You can have a look here as to how to modify KOMA vars with pandoc filters: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/scrlttr2/scrlttr2.lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a filter that'd add the `\publishers` command to the `header-includes` metadata field, which is then inserted in the document preamble.

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  if meta.publishers then
    local publishers = pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.publishers)
    meta["header-includes"] = {
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\publishers{' .. publishers .. '}')
    }
  end
  return meta
end
```

---

The document class is expected to be passed via the `documentclass` value, either in the metadata, or via a variable. There are some subtleties to metadata and variables, but in general, checking `meta.documentclass` should work. However, a better approach might be to define the `\publishers` command if it doesn't exist, e.g., by changing the filter to

```lua
    meta["header-includes"] = {
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\providecommand{\\publishers}[1]{}'),
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\publishers{' .. publishers .. '}')
    }
```

This will ensure that there won't be an error if a non-KOMA class is used, but the `\publishers` command will have no effect then.

---

There may be issues when trying to use the filter while also adding other content to include in the header, e.g. by calling pandoc with the `-H`/`--include-in-header` option. In that case you'll have to use a custom Lua writer to make it work. It's a bit less convenient though, because pandoc cannot infer the default template, so its path must be given explicitly:

```lua
local type = pandoc.utils.type

-- Convert a metadata value to Blocks
local to_blocks
to_blocks = function (x)
  if type(x) == 'Blocks' then
    return x
  elseif type(x) == 'Inlines' or type(x) == 'string' then
    return {pandoc.Plain(x)}
  elseif type(x) == 'List' then
    local accum = pandoc.List{}
    for i, b in ipairs(x:map(to_blocks)) do
      accum:extend(b)
    end
    return accum
  end
  return pandoc.Blocks{}
end

function Writer (doc, opts)
  local header_includes = opts.variables['header-includes'] or ''
  header_includes =
    pandoc.write(
      pandoc.Pandoc(to_blocks(doc.meta['header-includes'])),
      'latex'
    ) .. '\n' .. header_includes
  local latex = pandoc.write(doc, 'latex', opts)
  return latex
end
```

Use with

```sh
    pandoc -t mywriter.lua \
        -o out.pdf \
        --pdf-engine=xelatex \
        --template=data/default.latex
```

The path `data/default.latex` points to pandoc's default LaTeX template.

Comment: It looks right, but it does not work as expected. The command does not show up in the LaTeX document. The filter, however, is definitely executed.

Comment: @Matthias Are you using other options that would affect the content of `header-includes`, something like `-H` or `-V header-includes=x`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have `header-includes` and `include-in-header` in a defaults YAML file. When I remove them, the filter works.

Comment: @Matthias I've amended my answer to include a custom writer that will work even if you set `include-in-header`. It's not quite as convenient, but as you are already using a defaults file, it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @tarleb a simpler way to include a header file that's compatible with this method is to use: `pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\publishers{' .. publishers .. '}'), pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\input{header.tex}')`